# Appending a list to dataframe and adding count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and a list -

```
d={'abc':[0,2,4,5,2,2],'bec':[0,5,6,4,0,2],'def':[7,6,0,1,1,2],'rtr':[5,6,7,2,0,3],'rwr':[5,6,7,1,0,5],'xx':[4,5,6,7,8,7]}

X=pd.DataFrame(d)




   abc  bec  def  rtr  rwr  xx
0    0    0    7    5    5   4
1    2    5    6    6    6   5
2    4    6    0    7    7   6
3    5    4    1    2    1   7
4    2    0    1    0    0   8
5    2    2    2    3    5   7
    
l=[ 'bec','def','cef','ghd','rtr','fgh','ewr']
```

Now I want to append the list to data frame in the following way-

For each row in dataframe- We count the number of non zero elements in it(lets say it is 3 in the first row

We take 50% of 3= 1.5 (rounded to 1) and we append those many elements from the list l to the row(starting from the beginning). For the first row it is 'bec', since 'bec' is already present in the
row we increase its count by 1.

If the element from list is not present in the dataframe we append it at the end.

Dry run-

for row 1(index 1)- no of non zero elements is 6. So 50% of it is 3. So we take the first 3 elements from list['bec','def','cef']. 'bec' is already present so its count increases by 1 and it becomes(2,2)=6.
Similarly 'def' is present so it becomes(2,3)=7. 'cef' isn't present in the dataframe so we add it and make the count as 1.

The final output looks like this-

```
   abc  bec def rtr rwr xx cef
0   0   1   8   5   5   4   0
1   2   6   7   6   6   5   1
2   4   7   1   7   7   6   0
3   5   5   2   2   1   7   1
4   2   1   1   0   0   8   0
5   2   1   1   3   5   7   1
```

Comment: For row 2 the number of non zero elements is `5`, please edit your question and update the expected output accordingly.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I was talking about index 1 in this case but ill update it.it can be confusing.Thanks!

Comment: IMHO index should not be included in counting non-zero values as it doesn't makes sense. Are you counting index in addition to columns for any specific reason?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I understood what you meant..I was thinking I had 6 columns excluding a index. Thanks for the catch

Comment: @ubuntu-noob Please correct you expected output as per your latest edits.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ne` + `sum` along `axis=1` to count the non zero values in each row, followed by `floordiv` with `2` to consider only `50%` of these counts, next create a list of record with the help of `dict.fromkeys` method inside a list comprehension, now create a dataframe lets say `y` from these records and `add` it with `X` to get the desired result

```
y = pd.DataFrame(dict.fromkeys(l[:i], 1) 
                 for i in X.ne(0).sum(1).floordiv(2).astype(int))
X.add(y.fillna(0), fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

---

```
   abc  bec  cef  def  rtr  rwr  xx
0    0    1    0    8    5    5   4
1    2    6    1    7    6    6   5
2    4    7    0    1    7    7   6
3    5    5    1    2    2    1   7
4    2    1    0    1    0    0   8
5    2    3    1    3    3    5   7
```

Comment: i didn't realize dataframes could be initialized with a list of dicts -- very useful

Comment: and instead of 50% of non zeros elements..how can I take it as a variable from 5% to 30%?

Comment: In that case you can `floordiv` by `100/5` if you want to take `5%` of the values, similarly for `30%` `floordiv` by `100/30`

Comment: Im getting 
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method for  "for i in correctly_classified_samples.ne(0).sum(1).floordiv(100/5))" line..any idea how to fix that?

Comment: All the columns in my actual dataset are of type int64..i was trying to run this code there

Comment: @ubuntu_noob Please check `l[:int(i)]`

Comment: the i from the for loop is becoming float